# 3D image transform in opencv

Tags: python, opencv, scikit-image, image-manipulation, homogenous-transformation

I have a 4x4 homogenous transformation matrix I want to apply to an image in python. I found cv2.warpAffine for 2d space but can't find an equivalent function for the same task in 3d space. I am calculating this matrix from a 3d rotation vector and translation vector.

I tried getting separate rotation and translation matrices from my vectors but most resources I found required a 2d transformation (3x3 matrix) which negated my z axis transformation/rotation. I have also scoured the opencv/scikit-image documentation but thus far don't see anything that directly solves my problem.

Comment: It is unclear what you want to achieve. Do you want to transform the image to a 3D shape? That's either done by texture mapping (then you will need the 3D shape of the object and can define how to map - like having 2D map of the world and a 3D globe) or by projecting every pixel to sone depth. In general it is not possible to estimate the 3D position of a pixel only having the 2D image. Homography (warpPerspective) can warp a single plane to a single other plane (for example a 2D plane in 3D space).

Comment: If you have already calculated the 2d-projection of the rotated and translated four corners of the image you can apply `cv2.getPerspectiveTransform` and `cv2.warpPerspective`. If you still have questions, please add more details on what you want to achieve. Please read [ask].